# Универсальный апи для всех классов и для всех типов (добавление редактирование и удаление и показ)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Здравствуйте делаю на django универсальный апи на все классы со всеми методами.
в Джанго новичек. и решил таким способам изучить.
Вопросы:
1/ При инсерте не могу возвратить записанное поле возвратить пишет : 
Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'tuple'>` и не знаю как реализовать удаление чтоб статус возвращал 200 или 400

2/ Правильно ли я делаю если будут замечания по коду моему буду только рад)

Пока еще не подключил авторизацию и всякие фичи. Не проходите пожалуйста мимо скажите свое мнение. Спасибо

```
from collections import namedtuple

import null
from django.apps import apps
from rest_framework.response import Response

from .serializers import *
from .models import *
from rest_framework import generics, viewsets, status


class GeneralViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    myModel = null
    MyApiObj = null

    @property
    def api_object(self):
        return namedtuple("ApiObject", self.request.data.keys())(*self.request.data.values())

    @property
    def model(self):
        return apps.get_model(app_label=self.MyApiObj.app,
                              model_name=self.MyApiObj.object)

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        GeneralSerializer.Meta.model = self.myModel
        return GeneralSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        self.MyApiObj = self.api_object
        self.myModel = self.model
        return self.query_type()

    def query_type(self):
        if (self.MyApiObj.query == 'SELECT'):
            return self.select_api()
        elif (self.MyApiObj.query == 'INSERT'):
            return self.insert_api(),
        elif (self.MyApiObj.query == 'UPDATE'):
            return self.update_api(),
        elif (self.MyApiObj.query == 'DELETE'):
            return self.delete_api(),
        else:
            return Response('', status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        # print(self.MyApiObj.query)
        # query_select = {
        #     'SELECT':  self.select_api(),
        #     'INSERT':  self.insert_api(),
        #     'UPDATE':  self.update_api(),
        #     'DELETE':  self.delete_api(),
        # }
        # try:
        #     return query_select[self.MyApiObj.query]
        # except KeyError as e:
        #     return Response('', status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def select_api(self):
        queryset = self.myModel.objects.filter(**self.MyApiObj.filter)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def update_api(self):
        inserted = self.myModel.objects\
            .filter(**self.MyApiObj.filter)\
            .update(**self.MyApiObj.update)
        if (inserted):
            queryset = self.myModel.objects.filter(**self.MyApiObj.update)
            serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            return Response('', status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def insert_api(self):
        self.myModel.objects.create(**self.MyApiObj.create)
        queryset = self.myModel.objects.filter(**self.MyApiObj.create)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def delete_api(self):
        deleted = self.myModel.objects.filter(**self.MyApiObj.filter).delete()
        if (deleted):
            return Response('', status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response('', status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Вот сам пост апи для вызова

```
{
    "app": "leads",
    "object": "Lead",
    "query": "INSERT",
    "filter": {
    },
    "update": {
    },
    "create": {
        "name": "Test2",
        "email": "tes2t@gmail.com",
        "message": "I am test"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        elif (self.MyApiObj.query == 'INSERT'):
            return self.insert_api(),
        elif (self.MyApiObj.query == 'UPDATE'):
            return self.update_api(),
        elif (self.MyApiObj.query == 'DELETE'):
            return self.delete_api(),
```

Не будьте Л.Н.Толстым, экономьте запятые :)

PS: Вы забыли запятые, из-за чего метод стал кортежем из 1 элемента. Полагаю это произошлоиз-за копипаста какого то массива, который вы потом переработали. Уберите лишние запятые и ошибка исчезнет

---

По второму вопросу дать ответ не могу из-за отсутсвия подобного опыта

Comment: Юмор на 5 и ответ)) спасибо

Comment: Спасибо) Рад что оценили :)